# Triggering Notification from service when app is in background / killed

Tags: android, kotlin, service, notifications

I'm making a todolist app where the user needs to add a task along with date and time that i use later to trigger the notification , when app is in foreground , it works fine but since services are submitted to limitations after android oreo , now i'm lost on how to trigger the notification when app is in background or killed , if you guys could enlighten me , i woudl appreciate it

- This is my service class

```
  class NotificationService(var context: FragmentActivity) : Service(){
    private lateinit var remindersViewModel: remindersViewModel
    private lateinit var compat : NotificationManagerCompat
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        compat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
        remindersViewModel = ViewModelProvider(context)[remindersViewModel::class.java]
    }
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        isNotificationEnabled()

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun isNotificationEnabled(){
        //TODO : NOTIFICATION
        val notificationPrefs = getSharedPreferences("notificationPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val isNotificationEnabled = notificationPrefs.getBoolean("notification", false)

         remindersViewModel.getAllTasks().observe(context, Observer {
                 if(isNotificationEnabled){
                     CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                         delay(3000)
                         HandleOperations.taskNotification(it, context, compat)
                     }
             }
         })


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Oreo, all background services will be killed if not visible by a foreground service. The best case scenario for your problem is to use a Job Scheduler ([here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-job-scheduler/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0)).

For timely event based tasks Job Sceduler is the only options though it's no longer available in the support library.

You will also need a Notification Channel for devices with Oreo and above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  , but is it possible to push a notification using a jobschedular at an exact time , let's say for example 12:00 , would the notification be pushed exactly at 12:00